# Relationships and References in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, reference, schema, relationships, nosql

I am currently working on a project in which there are many threads that users can create. User's have different permissions for the threads that can be specified by users with admin permission. User's need to be added to the thread before they have access to it.

When a user is added to the thread, they are given either read, write or admin permission. Users can also be part of groups. These groups can then be added to a thread in which case, all users in the group will be added along with the permission that is specified for the group.

```
thread: {id: xxxxx, users:[{id:user01, permission: write, discovery: non}, {id:user02, permission: read, discovery: GroupA}]}
```

So a user can be added with an individual permission or they can be added with permission given to the group they are a part of. Discovery would specify whether the user was added individually or as a group.

I am wondering if this would be the best method of setting up Mongo for this sort of permission system and also how I would actually define this schema using Mongoose? I think that it would be fastest to have all these aspects embedded into each thread.

Comment: Really close http://stackoverflow.com/q/9443320/298389

Comment: Does that mean that embedding the permissions is the right thing to do?